# Do Spambots have access to unlimited IP addresses?

Tags: spam, ip-address

I have been attacked for weeks by the same spambot trying to brute force the login page. I have a login security module now installed on my Drupal 6 website and it bans on IP after x amount of attempts. It's been going on for ever and I have banned about 1000 IP addresses.

Is there any point in me banning on IP due to the spambot having access to unlimited IP addresses or will they run out of them eventually?

Comment: Have you looked at your raw access logs is there anything else you can ban them based on other than IP? If you could block them sooner it would help your server. Letting them get to the login page and only banning them after X amount of attempts is more like passive security than active.

Comment: To answer your question about spam bots having access to unlimited passwords yes. Aside from dictionary attacks which could have hundreds of thousands of word and word combinations they can have settings to brute force every combination of letters numbers and characters on a keyboard.

Comment: oh sorry Anagio my title is a typo and i will edit it. I meant IP Addressess not passwords.I never knew about the raw access log. i will go check it out. brb

Comment: excellent Anagio i think its some ukranian bot called ahrefs. they tell me on their site to add this to my robots txt. do i just add it at the bottom of my robots file as it is? user-agent: AhrefsBot
disallow:

Comment: actually i should be blocking them by htaccess shouldnt i? sorry this is ff topic. i will mark it as fixed

Comment: You might find Project Honeypot quite interesting, especially their [HTTP:BL](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl.php)

Comment: Not htaccess but robots.txt see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `robots.txt` file put

```
user-agent: AhrefsBot
disallow: /
```

from http://ahrefs.com/robot/

Comment: thanks Anagio. Truth be told that was the wrong thing. The fella is still at it. 60.13.171.105 - - [05/Dec/2012:05:40:24 -0500] "POST /welcome?destination=welcome HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "http://onlinebanter.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 Firefox/1.5.0.7"

Comment: his IP is changing every time. I cant find a way to stop him at all. He's beginning to wear me down :(

Comment: in my error logs i have this. this is another domain that i host for my sister. i dont know if it is related. it doesnt look good to me

Comment: 2012-12-05 06:08:26.581 [INFO] [HTAccess] Updating configuration from [/home/xxxxx/public_html/sites/default/files/.htaccess]
2012-12-05 06:07:58.417 [INFO] [HTAccess] Updating configuration from [/home/onlineba/public_html/.htaccess]
2012-12-05 06:07:12.111 [INFO] [HTAccess] Updating configuration from [/home/xxxxx/public_html/kittys-boutique.co.uk/.htaccess]
2012-12-05 06:07:12.111 [INFO] [HTAccess] Configuration file [/home/xxxxx/public_html/kittys-boutique.co.uk/.htaccess] changed

Comment: bahand when i check my sisters site i get this message An error occurred during a connection to kittys-boutique.co.uk.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_lon

Comment: phew sorry abou the above i realised what i did wrong. i tried to connect via https lol i can laugh now as i thought they where taking me down. again phew.

Comment: @RegGordon glad you got it cleared up

Comment: Nah the fella is still there Anagio but thanks for your help. I cant get rid of him at all. I think ive banned half the world by ip address but yet he continues to try to log in 5 times a minute. Ive gave up trying to fight him. Ive just added caching for guests to limit the blow. If my site cant handle 5 log ins a minute then maybe i should just give up.

Comment: You have the bot blocked in robots.txt and it's continuing to hit your site? Have you validated the robots.txt?

Comment: A blog post with comments about that bot http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_212.113.35.162

Comment: sorry Anagio it wasnt that bot at all. I was reading my Raw Access logs from top down thinking that the newest enteries where at the top. Its someone that managed to open a spam account when i had no protection a few months ago trying to brute force his login again (account banned and deleted) Im just gonna try and stop looking at my logs every minute and try and forget about him.

Comment: He has a differant ip every time and also changes his ip to get around Country Bans etc i put on now and again when it starts to get me down.  60.13.171.105 - - [05/Dec/2012:05:40:24 -0500] "POST /welcome?destination=welcome HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "onlinebanter.com/"; "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909

Comment: That seems like a lot of work for someone to get back into their account. What type of spam were they sending or posting? Also if you're on linux in terminal you can run tail -f your-access.log and it will show the last few lines and update in real time.

Comment: i forget what spam it was Anagio.i wish i could just let them back in now. My server is running at 100% CPU constant at the moment. Seems im getting every bot in town in my site. I wish i could add a captcha question server side. Folks have to answer a question just to view my site. I dont even care for google anymore.

Comment: Have you watched the bots in real time with wireshark to view what they're doing on the login pages? Naybe your got infected with some malware which is inviting them back. Rogue php file some place on y our server maybe. Try changing the form field names

Answer (score 1):

Spammers can use botnets to hit your site.   A botnet is a collection of internet devices that have been commandeered by a hacker.  The largest botnets have tens of millions of devices in them ([source](https://cybernews.com/security/the-8-biggest-botnets-of-all-time/)).   When somebody controlling a botnet wants to spam your site, they can use the devices from their botnet, each of which has its own IP address.

So while not truly "unlimited", some spammers have the ability to hit your site with enough IP address that blocking IP address won't be an effective strategy.

Most spam attacks don't come from hackers that have amassed a large botnet.   Blocking IP addresses will still be effective against the majority of spammers.